# How can I access the data/metadata of the Salesforce homepage via REST API?

Tags: rest-api, metadata

I'm trying to make my Salesforce application as dynamic as possible. One of the things I'd like to do is pull the meta-data and data that make up the Salesforce home page. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about it?

*Example of our current Salesforce Homepage*
[image]

*Using REST API 31.0*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not access Metadata API via REST.

However, you could use the [Metadata API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/) via SOAP. There you could retrieve three elements that define your Home:

- [HomePageLayout](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_homepagelayouts.htm)
- [HomePageComponent](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_homepagecomponent.htm)
- WebLinks

Finally, you could access via REST API to get the date your are exposing in the Home, typically:

- Tasks
- Events

For instance:

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/Event/ -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Good Luck